# How to append text in a QTextBrowser in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, filestream, qtextbrowser

I have created a `QTextBrowser` to display a large amount of data (actually displaying the run time log), which is dynamically generated in another processes.

I have found out that I can use `fopen("log.html","a")` to append data to an actually log file, and `reload()` it every time it's updated, but I think that's not efficient, or even possibly unwise.

I wonder if there's a neat way to implement this.

Comment: If you need a more performant version of append, you need to [access the internal QTextDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501745/performantly-appending-rich-text-to-qtextedit-or-qtextbrowser-in-qt/54501760#54501760).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got half way through writing this, supplemental to TonyK's answer:

Perhaps the [append](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#append) Method is what you're looking for?

> Appends a new paragraph with text to the end of the text edit. The new paragraph appended will have the same character format and block format as the current paragraph, determined by the position of the cursor. See also currentCharFormat() and QTextCursor::blockFormat().

Answer (score 26):

[`QTextBrowser`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html) inherits [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html), so you can use [`QTextEdit::append`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#append):

```
void QTextEdit::append ( const QString & text )
```

Comment: Thank you all the same! however i don't know how to choose multiple answers

Comment: @Topro: There can be only one accepted answer (with the green tick), but you can upvote as many answers as you like. To do so, you must click the little triangle pointing upward on the left of the answer. Similarly, if you think an answer is wrong or does not provide any useful information, you can downvote it with the triangle pointing downward.